# Change js variable value from code behind

Tags: javascript

I am calling a a javascript function in c# code behind using ScriptManager. I need to change a variable's(used as default height of a div) value just before the call to function.

Please suggest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a support function that sets the variable and then calls the function you want?

Comment: Appreciable idea, I thought like ScriptManager.RegesterClientScrip... there will any direct method.. thanks anyway